# Change color of active tabs in horizontal sub-menus with css

Tags: html, css

I have nested Horizontal Sub menus. I am having trouble with changing the color of active sun-menu tabs. The first tab is color blue so when the tab is active it is changed to red. Then when the sub menu is clicked the active sub-menu should change to grey and so its contents. I have attached the jsfiddle link below
https://jsfiddle.net/vgjcrpud/4/

I tried to access that particular nav-tabs using its id but no luck.

```
<style>
    .nav-tabs #submenu li.active{
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the active tab, you can use :

```
 #submenu > li.active > a{
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
```